# jwplayer black box issue

Tags: video, jwplayer

I dont't get why the video doesn't play? Has it to do with the format? mp4?

I am using jwplayer, because I want a non-flash solution/

Here is the link: http://www.2kfilms.com/jw_test.html

The code I am using tis the given:

```
`<div id='my-video'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('my-video').setup({
        file: 'http://www.2kfilms.com/jazz.mp4',
        width: '480',
        height: '270'
    });
</script>`
```

Comment: This plays fine for me in Firefox.